# Nativescript different api endpoint for dev/qa/prod environments strategy

Tags: nativescript

I have a NS app that talks to a web api backend.  I do not want to hardcode the api base url in the app itself because I need to be able to use different urls for development, testing, and production for different versions of the app.

E.g. Version 1.0 is in production and is pointing to https://someapi.com.  I am currently working on version 1.1 and I want to point that to https://dev.someapi.com during development and testing because I have API changes as well.  Once this version is QA'd and passes app store validation agains the test API.  I will push it to production, deploy the API, and point the version 1.1 from https://dev.someapi.com to https://someapi.com.

Currently, I have a database table that has the api endpoint for each version and environment, so if I needed to QA the app for version 1.1, I query the database when I load the app and get the api endpoint for this version and environment.

Is there a better way for doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use environment variable with [Nativescript CLI & Webpack](https://docs.nativescript.org/performance-optimizations/bundling-with-webpack). You may configure the URLs based on what environment you are building the app for.

There are lot of similar other ways around if you go through [Webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/).

Comment: I use that when I build for local testing, but how does it work when I bundle the app for deploy to the app store?

Comment: If you are looking to update the app that's already published, you may consider implementing [nativescript-app-sync](https://github.com/eddyverbruggen/nativescript-app-sync). Or you may use RemoteConfig from Firebase to update specific configurations of your app. Using your own APIs which I believe you are doing now is also good. It's totally opinion based.